# Does the initial polynomial of a Sturm sequence need to be normalized?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I've written an algorithm that generates a Sturm sequence and uses that sequence to determine the number of real roots over an interval.

My algorithm is working, but I made no precaution to normalize my polynomial i.e. to ensure that the leading coefficient is 1.

I've looked around for information on whether it needs to be normalized or not but without anything concrete - although all examples I see make use of a normalized polynomial.

Does the initial polynomial need to be normalized or not? If so, why is my algorithm still working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can multiply a polynomial by a constant factor (even negative) without influencing the roots. All derived polynomials will be multiplied accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense